# jQuery dialog not opening in IE8, but background overlay does

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, dialog

I'm using JQuery's dialog to have a message pop up when a user comes to a page, but it is supposed to only happen once per day. I've managed to get everything working, however when the code hits:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open')
```

Nothing happens. Now when I do:

```
modal: true,
```

And run it, the background overlay does come up, but not the actual dialog. I read a question where they said its a bug and to comment out a certain line, which I did but no change occurred.

It works just great in chrome, ff, etc..., just not IE8

Here is my code (just the related stuff of course):

```
<script src="http://testsite/JQuery/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://testsite/JQuery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://testsite/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://testsite/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="http://testsite/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="JQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">

function openpopup() {
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
}

function writeCookieTest() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 60 * 1000); // Just a minute to test
    document.cookie = "oncePerDay=true; expires=" + currentDate.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
}

function readCookieTest() {
    var name = "oncePerDay";
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 300
    });

    if (readCookieTest() != "true") {
        writeCookieTest();
        openpopup();
    }
});
</script>



<div id="dialog" title="Reminder!">
<p>This is the text to remind...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It seems to be an issue with not having all the needed scripts AND mixing versions of the scripts, the following jQuery scripts allow the dialog to work on IE8 with no problems:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css">

<script src="jQueryUI/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.effects.explode.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
```